# Bitbucket revert back to specific commit, then commit with message then push to feature branch

Tags: git

I did run into some examples when searching for a solution on SO. But none of them worked for what I needed to do.

When working in a feature branch, I need to revert back to a specific commit, then commit with a specific message, then push that to the same feature branch.

How is this done with git?

EDIT:

The commit I want to revert to has already been pushed to Bitbucket

Comment: Did you push your commits to BitBucket?

Comment: @Kryten yes, I still want to keep all the history also

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to revert back to a specific commit"? What do you want the end result to be? Do you want to throw away all of the commits since that commit? Or do you want to keep those commits but reverse their changes to your code?

Answer (score 1):

If the commits have been pushed to a remote repository and you want to keep all the history, the way to do it is to `git revert` all the commits that you need to "roll back". What you'll have is a history that looks like this:

```
edcba1 roll back bad commit #1
edcba2 roll back bad commit #2
edcba3 roll back bad commit #3
3abcde bad commit #3
2abcde bad commit #2
1abcde bad commit #1
```

Not pretty, but it very clearly indicates exactly what happened and it doesn't involve any rewriting of history (which, as you know if you've read many answers on SO is a very bad thing in a repository that others have pulled).